# What is the effect of coef0 in svm function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel, svm

As noted [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), I know that `coef0` is used in `polynomial` and `sigmoid` kernel functions in `SVM`. But what is the exact impact of this coefficient?

Answer (score 6):

Those are `kernel` parameters to your `SVM`/`SVC`.

As you see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-kernels):

[image]

Comment: Question: why does this answer deserve a down vote? Curious!

Comment: First to say: I didn't downvote. But a reason could be that you didn't answer the question. You only stated the kernels mathematical definition. But not everybody is able to extract the parameters impact on the model just from the mathematical definition. And that is exactly what op wanted to know, I guess.